# How to add up values in Excel while ignoring missing values (encoded 999)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please consider the following Excel worksheet:

```
    A  B   C    D   E    F
---------------------------
1  10  5  999  999  10   25
2   5  1   10  999   5   21
3   5  1  100   1    5  112
```

What I need is a formula in each cell of column `F`to add up the values of each row, whilst ignoring `999` values. So usually the formula in cell `F1` would be:

```
=SUM(A1:F1)
```

But this obviously returns 2048, not 25. So my question: what formula will add up all values, ignoring `999` (missing) values?

Comment: Can you replace all 999 values with 0? It seems easier to store that way...

Comment: `=SUMIF(A1:E1,"<999")`

Comment: @Passerby: Yup that is the way. However a slight amendment `=SUMIF(A1:F3,"<>999")` Also it is a valid answer. Why not post it ;)?

Answer (score 4):

Extending from comment (and thanks to @SiddharthRout):

You can use

```
=SUMIF(A1:E1,"<>999")
```

in column F.